# Can we present the current-driven BJT as two cascaded non-linear converters?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt

In the simple BJT current mirror, two non-linear converters - inverse (log) and direct (antilog), are cascaded. As a result, a linear relationship between the output and input current is obtained.

[image: Linearization]

[image: BJT current mirror]

If we can see the same configuration in the single transistor,  we will be able to explain in an intuitive way the linear relationship (Ic = beta x Ib) between the collector and base current.

In the BJT, the base-emitter voltage controls the collector current in an exponential manner. So if we directly drive the base-emitter junction by a perfect voltage source, the bare transistor can be thought as an "antilog voltage-to-current converter".

If we drive the base-emitter junction through a resistor or by a perfect current source, we will control indirectly the base-emitter voltage... and it will control the collector current as usual. So the base-emitter junction serves here as a "log current-to-voltage converter".

The conclusion is that, in this arrangement, there are two cascaded (reverse and direct) non-linear convertors. .. and the overall relation between the output quantity (collector current) and input quantity (base current) of this "aggregate" is linear - Ic = beta x Ib.

Is this a reliable viewpoint at the bipolar transistor and its current transfer characteristic... or I have fallen into some kind of a logical trap?

Comment: Your motivation for this complex way of looking at things is unclear.

Comment: Is there another intuitive way to explain linearity? If yes, please show it.

Comment: The only linear relation of a BJT is \$\beta=I_C / I_B\$ is that what you're asking? The relation \$I_C (V_{BE})\$ isn't linear. When feeding a current into the base and then considering \$V_{BE}\$ and how that then converts into \$I_C (V_{BE})\$ is overcomplicating things. When feeding a current into the base (and assuming \$V_{CE}\$ is large enough) then we can simply use \$I_C=\beta*I_B\$

Comment: Exactly... My question is if it is possible to explain, in this intuitive way, the linearity of this relation.

Comment: I'm not convinced your basis for this logic, that "base-emitter **voltage** controls the collector current", is a good starting point. It seems like your logic becomes circular after that...you make assumptions and then try to show that the combination of these assumption is consistent with the assumptions themselves.

Comment: This was my doubt...

Comment: I suggest that you study how a BJT works, focus on what defines the current amplification \$\beta\$. Also look at how the amount of carriers that flow into the base through the base contact relates to the collector current when the BJT is in active mode. This only becomes "intuitive" when you fully understand how a BJT works.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson....I agree to the second sentence of your comment. However, not to the first sentence. I rather think, the fact that "base-emitter voltage controls the collector current" is the only valid explanation for the observed current mirror effect - because equal VBE values for two transistors allows equal collector currents.

Comment: @LvW My problem is with the word **controls** which implies cause-and-effect. I much prefer to say that the base-emitter voltage has a known **relationship with** the base current, and the base current determines the maximum collector current.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson...and my problem (no, not really a problem....it is more a kind of doubt) is with your term "determines" which also implies cause-and-effect. Physically spoken - that is not the case. The base current is an unwanted by-product (Barrie Gilbert uses the word "nuisance")  that unfortunately very often is used for defining a "current gain"...and this term leads to a misinterpretation of the beta factor. The current mirror under discussion works only because of this voltage-to-current relation (Shockleys equation)

Comment: What a mess. It's dead simple. Ignoring base currents for now, the diode-connected BJT converts its collector current into the required base voltage needed to achieve it. This is then presented to the other BJT, which unsurprisingly since its collect acts like a current source, reproduces that collector current. Of course, reality impinges and there is the Early effect and the base currents needed and modest Ohmic resistances of the leads, the fact that the BJTs may not be well coupled thermally, and a host of nuances. But the basic concept is dead simple.

Comment: If it is so simple, how is a linear characteristic obtained by an element with a nonlinear characteristic? Anything is simple when you discern the idea behind it...

Comment: @Circuitfantasist You didn't mention my name with an at-sign, so I didn't see your comment until just now. (Very late.) The collector current on one side generates a non-linear Vbe function, which is passed over to the other BJT which converts it back using the inverse non-linear function. What in the heck is so hard to understand about that? The Vbe voltage is a log function of the collector current and the collector current is an exponential function of Vbe. So if you take the exp(ln(x)), what do you get? x, right? It is trivial! I mean.... anyone can see that, right?

Comment: @jonk, Sorry, I negligently forgot to mention your name... but in the future I will refer to it. Saying this, I first meant it is hard to explain this linearization in the case of a single transistor (Ic = beta x Ib). Next, I meant it is hard also to see how the antilog converter Ic = f(Vbe) is reversed to the opposite log converter Vbe = f(Ic). I respect you a lot; for me you are a beautiful mind in circuit theory...

Comment: @Circuitfantasist well, if we look at Ib as the fraction of Ie that is not collected by the collector, shouldn't it be clear that in a first approximation Ic has to be proportional to Ie and hence to Ic? I mean, if a carrier has a fixed chance x of getting out of base, the number of carriers being driven out (or in - depending on the polarity) of the base has to be proportional to the number of carriers supplied by the emitter. Things break down at low and high injection, but in the middle...

Comment: @Sredni Vashtar, I think there is a logic in your explanation. I see you try to find a physical explanation of this phenomenon. Rather, I am looking for a functional explanation based on the transistor behavior. I try to understand circuits as a circuiteer trying to figure out what the idea of connection is rather than what is inside the elements themselves...

Comment: @Circuitfantasist well, Ib and Ic are proportional due to the fixed probability of crossing the base, and the exponentials come into play because the number of carriers that have enough energy are determined by the Fermi Dirac distribution, whose tail is very well approximated by an exponential function. So you have two exponential functions that are (roughly) proportional to each other. This is the gist of transistor behavior, I don't think you can take it away from the whole circuit behavior. But I see you found your answer so...

Comment: @Sredni Vashtar, It sounds convincing... Why don't you write it as an answer?

Comment: @Circuitfantasist I gave up giving full-fledged answers on this site many months ago (maybe two years). The non-answers I received on Meta made me understand it is not worth the time spent. Something has changed, since then, but not enough. So I limit myself to leeching and commenting. :-)

Comment: @Sredni Vashtar, thanks for the revelation. There is really more to be desired here but after spending a total of 15 years in Wikipedia,  Wikibooks and ResearchGate, I have to admit that I feel best here...  maybe because my vocation is to be a teacher... and there are a lot of curious young people here asking fantastic questions. Everything here is lively, real and very dynamic... maybe this attracts me...

Comment: @Sredni Vashtar, I think I am starting to understand what you wanted to tell me in your last comment above... Really, I giviе too much of myself here and getting too little... I plan to minimize my participation here and come back to continue my "life-work" (Circuit Idea)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After not receiving a meaningful answer to my question for almost a month, yesterday I decided to answer my own question (the StackExchange policy allows and even encourages it).

I had no clear idea what the answer to the question was but I had the feeling that I would find it... ... and I found it. The magic word that helped me find it, was *"trans-"*. So, here is the simple answer in one sentence:

**Answer:** *Yes, we can present the current-driven BJT as two cascaded non-linear converters since the second one is a transconverter*.

This idea allows us, after assuming the Shockley equation as a starting point, to conclude that the collector current depends linearly on the base current. The power of this approach lies in its versatility because it can explain various specific implementations.

**Conceiving the idea.** Even when I asked this question a month ago, my intuition was telling me that it was so... but I could not defend my thesis convincingly... and yesterday I found the solution. I came to this insight after analyzing in detail the BJT current mirror above and so I realized the role of the input transistor T1 (the so-called "active diode"). Here is the evolution of my reasoning...

**Current mirror example.** The key point here is that it is not the "active diode" that makes the current mirror... and it is not the one that provides the linearity; *both they are provided by the humble second transistor*. Indeed, it is not exactly a *current mirror*; it is rather a linear *current amplifier* since Ic = beta x Ib = beta x Iin. That is why the input "active diode" is connected in parallel to the base-emitter "diode" - to divert the excess input current and leave only the small base current so Ic = Iin. It is not connected to ensure the input log conversion since the second transistor does it itself by its base-emitter junction; it is connected to equalize the input and output currents.

**Generalization.** This conclusion (linear relation) applies to *every transconductance converter which input behaves as the opposite converter*... or, in other words, it applies to every 2-port voltage-to-current (transconductance) converter which input behaves as a 1-port current-to-voltage converter. In our example the BJT is an antilog transconverter (a "transdiode" controlled by voltage at one place that produces current at other place) which input is a log converter (a diode controlled by current that produces voltage at the same place). Note the ordinary transconductance (voltage-to-current) converter does not obey this idea since it can have a true voltage input (with extremely high resistance). Its input must be conductive... and with the opposite relation. So we can emulate it by connecting an external element (diode) in parallel to the input. For example, imagine the MOSFET transfer characteristic was exponential like BJT. The problem is that its input is extremely high resistive (open circuit). So we can connect a diode in parallel to the gate-source input to immitate the BJT base-emitter junction; thus the whole combination will act as a BJT with linear relation Id = k.Iin.

Note this trick does not only serve to linearize the transfer charactersitic but to make a current-to-current converter by cascading a current-to-voltage and voltage-to-current converters. It does not only mirror the current magnitude but also inverts the current direction. That is why a current mirror can be called *current inverter* as well.

**Variations.** BTW it seems the opposite is possible as well but not so useful - to make a voltage-to-voltage converter by cascading a voltage-to-current and current-to-voltage converters. Interesting... it seems the op-amp inverting amplifier is such an example where R1 acts as the input voltage-to-current converter and the rest (R2 and the op-amp) acts as a current-to-voltage converter (transimpedance amplifier). The transfer ratio is linear. But it would be linear even we replace the ohmic R1 and R2 with nonlinear resistors (e.g., diodes)... a quite odd and somehow conflicting configuration... In this case we will apply input voltage and will obtain output voltage... and the relation between them will be linear.

**Rebuttal.** So, I have not fallen into a logical trap. This would have happened if I had tried to see this idea in an ordinary 2-terminal converter - the diode. That would mean I wanted to take the input current flowing through the diode as output current... which would be absurd...

Comment: The whole story reminds me on the subject of signal processing in the log-domain ("quasilinear" between input and output).

Comment: @LvW, like cascaded "compressor" and "expander" in audio amplifiers (Dolby)?

Comment: For example: An active 1st-order lowpass in the log-domain consists of 2 classical current mirrors (both emitter connected to each other) and one capacitor between the emitters and ground. Input and output quantities are currents.

Comment: @LvW, My observation here is only about the case where the input port of a transconverter behaves as the opposite converter. Then we can consider this single converter as consisted of two cascaded converters (ordinary and "trans-")...